# What should be done with my own old forgotten questions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, accept-rate

I revisited old questions I asked a long time ago for which I didn't accept any answers.

It was somewhat problematic.

- I do not need an answer any more. For some reason, the question is now irrelevant (abandoned project or whatever).
- I do not even recall if I solved the issue or not
- If I did solve it, I do not recall if it was using the answer or not.
- In some cases, I didn't dig enough in the issue to gain enough experience to pick an answer

Should I blindly accept the seemingly best answer, delete the question or just leave it there *to rot*?

I was considering deletion because the answers might be bad. Someone with a similar issue might be dissatisfied with the answers and having the question already asked, he might not ask it again (duplicate).

Although, deletion might remove some useful answer that I cannot grasp...

And picking an answer blindly just to increase my accept rate really sounds dumb. (I'm going accept that `2+2 != potato` because it quite possibly true!)

[related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153345/found-out-my-bug-was-just-barking-at-the-wrong-tree-should-i-accept-answers)

Comment: If any of the answers were upvoted, you can't delete it. (P.s. 2+2 does equal potato. Glad to help)

Comment: see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88346/under-which-circumstances-should-i-delete-my-own-question-or-answer) and ones _linked_ there, especially [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/i-no-longer-need-an-answer-to-a-question-what-should-i-do-to-the-question)

Answer (score 8):

You never need to accept an answer. No one should ever bother you about your accept rate. If a question has no answer that inspires you to accept it, then don't accept *any*.

Comment: I should have left out the _blindly accepting answers_ since it's the less relevant part.

Comment: Because the team hasn't gotten around to removing it, in spite of all the posting here about its counterproductivity.

Answer (score 4):

Are the questions still useful?  See if you can edit them into a form that future visitors might find useful by removing noise, adding detail, or whatever else needs to be done to make it into a good questions.  Maybe you can nudge the question from something fairly open-ended into something which at least supports its highest voted answer.

If the questions aren't useful (maybe the question is now too localized or not a real question, or even a dupe of another question) you can flag appropriately, or vote to close.  Or even delete your own question - if it's really a waste of cognitive effort for everyone who sees it, it can go away.