# Community-wikify old question (now irrelevant for me)?

Tags: support, community-wiki, old-questions

Approximately one year ago [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361037/using-springs-localvalidatorfactorybean-with-jsf). This question is not relevant for me anymore since I've stopped using that specific technology.

Since I don't know what to do with this question I'll ask the experts. Before asking, I of course used the search and came up with [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155695/what-should-be-done-with-my-own-old-forgotten-questions). However, no accepted answer and it doesn't discuss making old questions community wiki.

My answer is upvoted twice, at the time of writing, so removing it seems like a bad move. Accepting an answer, that I cannot verify, is even worse. Just leaving it there also seems like I'm sending out the wrong message (that I'm still looking for an answer).

Since I cannot accept an answer I thought of making it more open (community wiki). I can't spot the community wiki checkbox so I guess this isn't possible. Should I add a note stating that I'm not looking for an answer anymore or should I bother a more privileged user (mod?) to make it community wiki?

Comment: If you make the question CW, all the new answers would be CW. That's why the author can't make a question CW.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. I'm pretty sure CW is _not_ the right solution here, but I'm not really sure _what_ is. I think the real problem, though, is that the question has been pretty neglected by the community. I mean, not a single vote on the answers by _anybody_, really?

Comment: You can flag for moderator's attention and ask to disassociate question from your account. They may or may not agree, but since you are not trying to avoid any kind of ban by doing it (non-negative score), you have a chance.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for the suggestion. I would like a confirmation of someone else though (no offence). Since you've added a comment instead of a question I feel as though you're not certain of this solution.

Comment: @siebz0r only SO diamonds can definitely answer this. I know you can flag, but how real is the chance they will do that for you? Not something I can know.